# form styling difference in firefox and chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a form element for my project. I designed it using Firefox. It looks okay in Firefox. But when I tested it on chrome it gets distorted. Some elements moved down a little and some element tends to move out of the boundary. How I can fix this type of issue?

In Firefox:

[image: demonstration]

In chrome: (**register button at the bottom moves further down**)

[image: demonstration]

```css
    #mydiv{
     width:90%;
     height:640px;
    position:relative;
     left:20px;
     border-radius:4px;
     border:1px solid black;
     top:0px;
     margin-bottom:20px;
     margin-top:40px;
      margin-bottom:100px;
     box-sizing:border-box;

  }

   #forwrite{
   width:400px;
     height:560px;
    position:absolute;
     left:430px;
     top:0px;
     border:1px solid black;
     border-top-left-radius:5px;
     border-top-right-radius:5px;
     margin-bottom:20px;
     margin-top:40px;
      margin-bottom:100px;
     box-sizing:border-box;
   }

    .whole{

     width:100%;
     height:auto;
     background:#ececec;
     padding:8px;
     box-sizing:border-box
  }
  .design{

     font-size:15px;
     font-weight:bold;

  }
  .field{
     width:85%;
     height:26px;
     position:relative;
     left:60px;

  }

  .wrapper{
    position:relative;
    right:40px;
    padding:8px;
  }

  #register{
     background:#18c785;
     font-size:27px;
     border-top-left-radius:5px;
     border-top-right-radius:5px;
     color:white;
     width:100%;
     height:60px;
  }
  #headwrapper{

     box-sizing:border-box;

  }
  #registerbutton{
     position:relative;
     left:150px;
     top:6px;
     width:89px;
     height:40px;
     cursor:pointer;
     border-radius:6px;
     background:#18c785;
     color:white;
     font-size:20px;
  }
  .design label{
     font-size:24px;
  }
```

```html
<form >
<div id='forwrite'>

   <div id='headwrapper'><div id='register'>Registration Form </div></div>
   <div class='whole'>
        <div class='design'>
            <label for='username'>Username</label>
        </div>
        <div class='wrapper'>
             <input type='text'  class='field' placeholder='Username' name='username' value='' autocomplete='off'>
        </div>
   </div>

   <div class='whole'>
        <div class='design'>
            <label for='password'>Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class='wrapper'>
            <input type='password' class='field' name='password' placeholder='Password' value='' autocomplete='off'>
        </div>
   </div>

   <div class='whole'>
        <div class='design'>
            <label for='password_again'>Re-enter password</label>
        </div>
        <div class='wrapper'>
            <input type='password' class='field' placeholder='Type Password Again' name='password_again' value='' autocomplete='off'>
        </div>
   </div>

   <div class='whole'>
        <div class='design'>
            <label for='name'>Full Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class='wrapper'>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Full Name' class='field' name='name' value='' autocomplete='off'>
        </div>
   </div>

    <div class='whole'>
        <div class='design'>
            <label for='email'>Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class='wrapper'>
            <input type='text' class='field' placeholder='Your email' name='email' value='' autocomplete='off'>
        </div>
   </div>

   <div id='button'>
       <input type='submit' value='register' id='registerbutton'>
   </div>
   <input type='hidden' name='token' value="">

 </div>

</form>
```

Comment: I'd like to mention that the bug appears on Safari as well. So we can assume that every Webkit browser is affected.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into something called normalise.css

Link: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Description: 'Normalize.css makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. It precisely targets only the styles that need normalizing.'

Taken from the site, pretty handy tool especially for your situation

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Paulie_D woops sorry comment police.

Comment: You're right...it would be useful but it's not *actually* an answer.

Comment: do i need to remove my own css file to use it ?

Comment: @AL-zami no, you can use both in conjunction.